# Javascript added via drupal_add_js() does not get aggregated

Tags: performance, javascript

I have a couple custom modules that I add javascript via drupal_add_js(). I have all the Bandwidth Optimizations options checked in the performance page (/admin/config/development/performance).

Since I have Aggregate JavaScript files checked, should all my javascript files be aggregated into one file? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Well, that's weird. I tried `drupal_add_js()` myself and the file is being aggregated correctly, where in your code is called `drupal_add_js()`? Make sure the `preprocess` option isn't set to FALSE by another module.

Comment: Agreed. Can you show us an example of one of your files that is not being aggregated?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since the question is about code, you should show the code you are using, or the question is not much helpful to future readers, which is what Stack Exchange aims. Also, it is difficult to say what you are doing wrong without actually seeing what you are doing. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't aggregating is that someone had every_page set to FALSE and preprocess set to FALSE(as @thedotwrite was saying in comment above) in a lot of  drupal_add_js() calls.  (Some of them were set like this because they really shouldn't have been on every page but there were some that really could be on every page).

Not sure why I didn't notice that before :)